# YUV420p to other formats, color shift problems

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ffmpeg, yuv

So I'm writing a color detection application using an AR Drone. The drone sends my python/opencv socket server an image from its camera in YUV420p format.

What I do to access the image as an opencv IPLImage is the following (and yes this is inefficient but I didn't / don't want to have to write new conversion tools myself):

1. Save the yuv image to a file (some_image.yuv)
2. subprocess.call(*insert ffmpeg call here*)
3. Read the resultant file (bmp, png, it doesn't matter) back in using cv.LoadImage

My problem right now is a very noticable color shift. I'm waving a red felt sheet in these pictures. The first one shows a heavy yellow tint. The second isn't as bad but is very rare -- mostly when I have the red sheet it's heavily tinted.

- Tinted image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQikM.png
- Less-tinted image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezHyy.png

I'm wondering both of these things:

1. if there's either a better way to do this
2. If the color tinting issue can be resolved

My ffmpeg conversion line looks something like

```
ffmpeg -s 640x480 -vcodec rawvideo -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -i image.yuv -vcodec bmp -f image2 output.bmp
```

I've also tried:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s 640x480 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf colormatrix=bt709:bt601 -i image.yuv -f image -vcodec png output.png
```

The color shift is always there, unfortunately!

The color shift is my big problem right now as I later convert the image to HSV and use thresholding to choose a color range that works for me.

Comment: You should also include the complete ffmpeg console outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach seems to work for me:

```
$ ffmpeg -s 352x288 -i foreman_cif_frame_0.yuv f.png
ffmpeg version N-46810-g7750c48 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 21 2013 11:12:24 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame
  libavutil      52.  7.100 / 52.  7.100
  libavcodec     54. 71.100 / 54. 71.100
  libavformat    54. 36.100 / 54. 36.100
  libavdevice    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 23.100 /  3. 23.100
  libswscale      2.  1.102 /  2.  1.102
  libswresample   0. 16.100 /  0. 16.100
  libpostproc    52.  1.100 / 52.  1.100
[rawvideo @ 0x18a1320] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'foreman_cif_frame_0.yuv':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 352x288, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Output #0, image2, to 'f.png':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.36.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 352x288, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo -> png)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    
video:201kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.000000%
```

output:

[image: Famous forman as png]

Another approach is using the mighty [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

```
$ convert -size 352x288 -depth 8 foreman_cif_frame_0.yuv f2.png
```

Interestingly, ffmpeg and imagemagick do not return identical results:

```
$ compare -compose src f.png f2.png diff.png
```

Result:

[image]

**update**
Too bad. The only reasonable explanation then is that PIL is borked (it has some peculiarities when it comes to YCbCr handling; many Q here on SO about that). As you can see from my post, if the input is correct YCbCr, the the output is OK!

If I read your Q correct, you already receive the data in [YV12](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#YV12) format.
Input is in VGA so the following code splits the separate planes (Y, Cb, Cr) into own variables:

```
# Here I'm assuming you get the data from the drone into parameter raw
# 1 frame contains 640*480*3/2 = 460800 bytes
import numpy as np

# turn raw into a numpy array
raw = np.array(raw)

# calculate where each plane starts and stops
wh = 640 * 480
p = (0, wh, wh, wh/4*5, wh/4*5, wh/2*3)

# Now use slizing to extract the different planes
yy = np.empty(640*480, dtype=np.uint8)
cb = np.empty(640*480/4, dtype=np.uint8)
cb = np.empty(640*480/4, dtype=np.uint8)

yy = raw[p[0]:p[1]]
cb = raw[p[2]:p[3]]
cr = raw[p[4]:p[5]]
```

Now you have the data in nice numpy array! To convert into a matrix, do:

```
yy.reshape([480, 640])
cb.reshape([480 / 2, 640 / 2])
cr.reshape([480 / 2, 640 / 2])
```

Hope it helps! If not, drop me a comment...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response Fredrik. Unfortunately your parameters for ffmpeg and convert do pretty much the same thing that my ffmpeg line does. The color shift still happens, and it's very weird. Red turns yellowish, everything else turns greenish :/

Comment: Thanks Fred, so I determined that the problem was in fact the camera itself. For some reason, even using AR Drone's provided C firmware which has a YUV to RGB converter, strong reds or blues would tint the picture.

My solution was to use a neutral density filter over the camera to normalize incoming light. It greatly alleviated the problem!